# Vertical video sretched in Video View

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, behavior

I am working for play video in video view. Horizontal video plays plays awesome, but when i played the vertical video it stretched to full width of the screen rather that playing it as per vertical ratio.

Here is my xml view.

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/playerHeight"
        android:background="@color/black">

       <com.controlcastappplayer.customviews.MyVideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="visible" /></FrameLayout>
```

I am using custom video view

Here is the class for the custom video view

```
public class MyVideoView extends VideoView {

private int mVideoWidth;
private int mVideoHeight;

public MyVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MyVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public MyVideoView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public void setVideoSize(int width, int height) {
    mVideoWidth = width;
    mVideoHeight = height;
}


@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    Log.i("@@@", "onMeasure");
    int width = getDefaultSize(mVideoWidth, widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = getDefaultSize(mVideoHeight, heightMeasureSpec);
    if (mVideoWidth > 0 && mVideoHeight > 0) {
        if (mVideoWidth * height > width * mVideoHeight) {
            Log.i("@@@", " onMeasure image too tall, correcting");
            height = width * mVideoHeight / mVideoWidth;
        } else if (mVideoWidth * height < width * mVideoHeight) {
            Log.i("@@@", "onMeasure image too wide, correcting");
            width = height * mVideoWidth / mVideoHeight;
        } else {
            Log.i("@@@", "onMeasure aspect ratio is correct: " +
                    width + "/" + height + "=" +
                    mVideoWidth + "/" + mVideoHeight);
        }
    }
    // Log.i("@@@", "setting size: " + width + 'x' + height);
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}}
```

**By using this code my video stretch like this.**

[image]

**but my need is video should look and play like this.**

[image]